# How to readQuery() and writeQuery() from Vue-Apollo Store?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I want to edit some data in the cache manually.

How can I `readQuery()` and `writeQuery()` in vue-apollo directly from a method of a Vue component? Im looking for something like `this.$apollo.readQuery(...)`, which does not work. Where do I get the `store` instance from?

I mean the store instance from `update()` method in e.g. `this.$apollo.mutate`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside a component you can grab the methods from `this.$apollo.provider.defaultClient`

```
  methods: {
    async doQuery (my_data) {
      const apolloClient = this.$apollo.provider.defaultClient
      apolloClient.writeQuery({
        query: QUERY,
        data: {
          data: my_data,
        },
      })
    },
```

Comment: If you want to use another client: `this.$apollo.provider.clients.yourClientName`